# SQL Join hardcoded array to results 1-to-1

Tags: sql, postgresql, colors

I am trying to supply an array of color hex codes to a query, and I need one value lined up with each result, preferably with the color list looping if it runs out.

I'm trying to use `unnest(ARRAY[])` with the colors hardcoded as about 15-20 strings.

```
UNNEST(ARRAY['9A2849', '0F910F', 'A3915D', 'D49D2F', 'E87B00',
    '09A6B3', '007DC3', '969696', '005788', '086908', '706545', 
    '996600', '801131', '606060', 'BA5004', '008596']) AS color
```

I can't get a `JOIN` to work, since they require an `ON` clause.

Specifically, I'm trying to provide some reasonable colors for a pie chart, without having to add a color table or create some sort of random color generator in SQL.

Is there an easy way to add a column of hardcoded data that lines up 1-to-1 with selected data? If so, is there an easy to make the hardcoded data loop when its end is reached? (If not, I can limit the select to the largest 25 results, since any more will be slivers on a pie chart anyway.)

The results should be something like:

```
value | label                 | color
-----------------------------------------
2     | "A test for cloning"  | "9A2849"
6     | "Automobile Bays"     | "0F910F"
2     | "Break Rooms"         | "A3915D"
3     | "Common Areas"        | "D49D2F"
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a left, right or full join, rather than an inner join.

Comment: I just tried a `CROSS JOIN`, and it just gave me the first value from the array for each row of my results. As far as I'm aware, all the other `JOIN`s require an `ON` condition, and what condition could I use?

Comment: What data are you starting with?

Comment: @muistooshort - the example results I provided above would be the same, just without the "color" column.

Comment: But how do you know that value=2 gets color=9A2849 ? Is there some column that you're using to order things and you just want to match things up sequentially?

Comment: Ah. They're sorted alphabetically be label. Value is the number of occurrences, ie the portion of the pie chart that the label will be linked to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a row number % the number of colors you have and joining on that:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY numb DESC) AS POSITION FROM tab) t
JOIN (SELECT UNNEST( ARRAY['9A2849', '0F910F', 'A3915D', 'D49D2F', 'E87B00','09A6B3', '007DC3', '969696', '005788', '086908', '706545',
    '996600', '801131', '606060', 'BA5004', '008596']) AS color,  UNNEST( ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]) AS numb
   ) x 
ON t.POSITION % 16 + 1 = x.numb;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/00823/3

From Mu's comment:

```
SELECT (ARRAY['9A2849', '0F910F', 'A3915D', 'D49D2F', 'E87B00','09A6B3', '007DC3', '969696', '005788', '086908', '706545',
    '996600', '801131', '606060', 'BA5004', '008596'])[t.position% 16 + 1] AS color, *
FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY numb DESC) AS POSITION FROM tab) t
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/00823/10

Comment: You don't even need the JOIN/UNNEST for this, you can say things like `select ... (array[...])[n % 16 + 1] from (select *, row_number() over ...)` and move the array wrangling right into the outer SELECT.

Comment: @muistooshort That would be better, but I can't make that work.  What exactly is the syntax?

Comment: Something like this: `select value, label, (ARRAY[...])[n % 16 + 1] from (select value, label, row_number() over () as n from T) as dt`. Just fill in the order conditions and the ARRAY content, the tricky part is wrapping the array literal in parentheses.

Comment: That's what I was missing, no parens.  Very cool, did not know you could do that.